# Can't locate Mojo/DOM.pm in @INC (you may to install the Mojo::DOM module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.2)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mojolicious

I've got many troubles , i want to install Mojo::DOM and i cant find a guide to install it on the internet.

Comment: This seems like its confusing because there is one thing called mojo which is html javascript stuff and mojolicious which is perl and has all references to mojo::dom.  So I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo

Answer (score 3):

```
apt install libmojolicious-perl
```

or

```
cpan install Mojo::DOM
```